# What is the datatype used for percentage in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, type-conversion

For example The values for percentage are like 15.90% , 25.80% etc.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

```
DECIMAL(p,s)
```

Percent is only a presentation concept: 10% is still 0.1

Edit: simply, decide precision and scale for the highest expected values/desired decimal places when expressed as real numbers. You can p = s for values < 100% and simply decide based on decimal places

Edit2:

However, if you do need to store 100% or 1, then you'll need p = s+1.

This then allows up to 9.xxxxxx or 9xx.xxxx%, so I'd add a check constraint to keep it maximum of 1 if this is all I need.